# Got "An Error has occured" while upvoting answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I couldn't repro this so don't have more info, but I received "An Error has Occured" while trying to upvote an answer. What I *think* happened was I tried to open the comments section for the answer while it was still handling the upvote. 
There is no error sitting in my FF error console for it. 
Going back to the main list, then to the question again, I could upvote it successfully.

Comment: General problems with the SE software would probably be better aimed at meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are usually one time occurrences that could be anything from a random dropped connection, error in downloading, an upgrade was going on, your router hating you, anything. A refresh should fix it.